# Auto Answer Powershell Prompts from Scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, prompt

I have written a powershell script which uses a third party Cmdlet (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OdooCmdlets/21.0.8137.1).

The script is working fine on my local enviroment, but i need to apply it to an Azure Function to generate a daily execution (since it process data into a Azure SQL Database).

On its first line (*see script below*), i have establish the connection parameters where a prompt / pop-up window appears, which is easy to anwser when via user interaction from a local enviromnt (Powershell ISE)

[image: Prompt / Pop-Up Detail]

However, when i try to run the script on the azure function the following error appears:

*ERROR: A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: Would you like to install a license now? (You may use "TRIAL" as the Product Key to activate a trial license.)*

I need to adapt the script in order to auto-anwser the prompt / pop-up window, or find another solution.

Powershell Script:

```
Import-Module OdooCmdlets
$odoo = Connect-Odoo -User 'xxxxx' -Password 'xxxx' -URL 'xxxxx' -Database "xxxx"
```

Comment: Execute `Import-Module OdooCmdlets; Get-Help Connect-Odoo -Full` and look for parameters to suppress this prompt. Maybe you can also install a license _before_ calling `Connect-Odoo`, which may prevent this prompt.

Comment: Solved! i have just applied the RTK parameter and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the cmdlets before but inspecting the help files: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OdooCmdlets/21.0.8137.1/Content/lib%5Cnet20%5CCData.OdooCmdlets.Commands.dll-help.xml it appears there is an `-RTK` parameter available.

Is it possible you have a key which you can pass as part of the connection which would suppress the prompt?

Failing that, the developer docs have examples for Python which you could either translate to PowerShell and not use the Cdata Odoo module or just use python in your Azure Functions

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/misc/api/external_api.html

Comment: Solved! i have just applied the RTK parameter and it works.